# Python:find a number in a list (smaller but the biggest one)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, list

Assume we are using python:
If an int number `a` , and a list of int numbers are given. We are supposed to find this very number :
It should be smaller than `a`;
It is the biggest one in all the numbers that are smaller than `a`;

for ex. `a=3, list=[1,2,3,4]`, and the very number should be `2`.

How should I reach this without any outside packages?

Comment: A simple `for` loop? What have you tried?

Comment: Show the code you tried so we can help.

Comment: I come out how to do it with your hint. I made it by a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a comparison of different solutions, all of the answers are asymptomatically O(n). Here I compared three of them in a jupyternotebook using magic functions `%memit` and `%timeit`:

```
import timeit
import random
%load_ext memory_profiler
l = list(range(100000)) # Create a long list
random.shuffle(l)       # Let's shuffle the list
a = 50000               # Set the target variable the middle element
```

Here is a function that does what the question wants:

```
def max_less_than(a,l):
    c = None
    for i in l:
        if i < a:
            c = max(c,i) if c else i
    return c
```

Here are two solutions based on list comprehension and filter:

```
result = max([x for x in l if x < a]) 
result = max(filter(lambda x: x < a, l))
```

Let's profile them with `timeit`; I ran each of them in four rounds each round with 1000 iterations, you may increase the rounds/iterations for more accurate results:

```
%timeit -n 1000 -r 4 max_less_than(a,l)
# 13.5 ms ± 588 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit -n 1000 -r 4 max(filter(lambda x: x < a, l))
# 15.7 ms ± 248 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit -n 1000 -r 4 max([x for x in l if x < a])
# 8.07 ms ± 301 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Seems that list comprehension beats the other two in CPU performance. But let's check the memory as well:

```
%memit max_less_than(a,l)
# peak memory: 53.86 MiB, increment: 0.13 MiB
%memit max(filter(lambda x: x < a, l))
# peak memory: 53.75 MiB, increment: 0.12 MiB
%memit max([x for x in l if x < a])
# peak memory: 54.23 MiB, increment: 0.48 MiB
```

The reason that filter-based approach uses significantly less memory is its [generator-like](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) nature. In the sense that the elements of a filter object are not going to be stored in memory, but they are evaluated one-by-one when some operation is taking place on the object.
So in summary, if your main concern is memory efficiency (like the cases that your solution requires creating long sequences over and over again) you might be better to consider generator-based built-ins.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the list is stored in l = [1,2,3,4,5], [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) built-in function can give you the elements that a condition is true for:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = 3
f = filter(lambda x: x < a, l) #This stores elements that are smaller than a in a filter object
num = max(f) # filter is an iterable and max() built-in is difined on it
# num == 2
```

Comment: Thank you.I found that using lambda function makes code simple and beautiful!

Comment: I found it to be quite slower on big lists than Suresh or Sociopath solutions.

Comment: @Vince I added a new answer comparing the performance of different approaches. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need `list comprehension` with `max`:

```
a = 3
l = [1,2,3,4]
print(max([x for x in l if x<a]))
# 2
```

Answer (score 2):

max of of matched list will do

```
a=3
list=[1,2,3,4]
max_val=max([el for el in list if el < a])
print (max_val)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing the same can be this:

```
 l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 a = 3
 def fun(x): return x < a
 f = filter(fun, l)
 num = max(f)
 print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(x in array)
 if(x = yournum - 1)
   result = x
```

Just do a for loop of each element.

Comment: what if yournum-1 is not in list ?